# Populating ListBox from textbox search fields

Tags: vb.net, listboxitem, system.io.directory

I'm trying to figure out the simple reason why the ListBox isn't populating, the purpose is to find files in a directory. Files typically look like `FY12 Month02 BMD Mold Line.pdf` and so I made three text boxes for year, month, and type. I'd also like to know what would be the best way to use `CONTAINS` for three search fields for one filename?

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim year, month, type As String
    year = InternalAuditYear.Text
    month = InternalAuditMonth.Text
    type = InternalAuditType.Text

    Dim FileList As String() = Directory.GetFiles("X:\Internal audits\", ".pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    For Each foundFile As String In FileList
        Dim GOTCHA As String = Path.GetFileName(foundFile)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(GOTCHA)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Given the code you've provided, the only reason I can see for no listbox items is that FileList is empty.  Have you verified you're getting any results?

Comment: I've debugged it multiple times, but I found out I was missing the asterisk symbol on .pdf. Should be "*.pdf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the reason why your ListBox is not populating is because `Directory.GetFiles()` is not returning any results.  This is due to the searchPattern parameter `".pdf"` it needs a wildcard character (`*`).

Try...

```
Directory.GetFiles("X:\Internal audits\", "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

However, this is also dependent that there are files that end with `.pdf`.

Comment: I love coding, but I hate it when I rip my hair out for something as simple as a fix of one character * GRR. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for file name separation you could use a simple .Split(' ') which you can test on arraysize before you use it... should be something like this (don`t have VB.Net handy right now):

```
    Dim fileName As String = "FY12 Month02 BMD Mold Line.pdf"
    Dim splitFileName() As String = fileName.Split(New Char() {" "c})

    If (splitFileName.Length > 4) Then
        'OK, proper file name
        year = splitFileName(1)
        month = splitFileName(2)
        type = splitFileName(3)
    End If
```

Your other problem: see if the listbox item are there when debugging. If yes try to manually refresh the form. If not you didn't get the path right. (Maybe drive X: isn`t available when running the program)

Comment: type will only have "BMD" and not "BMD Mold Line"

Comment: I think it will be very easy to alter the code to meet your requirements (like type = splitFileName(3) + " " + splitFileName(4) + " " + splitFileName(5) )